# Java GAE backend restarts in under 3 mins Error 202

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I have using Java GAE with HR features
I have configured a Backend triggred from a Push Queue.
I am fetching 5000 recs with further processing.
The back restarts in under 3 mins with Error 202.

*"W 2013-03-22 04:12:30.644
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 202)"*

I request someone from Google to respond.

Even though the Queues can run for 10 mins, none of the queue ever run mire than 3 mins.

I do not know if there is way to config this.

Let me know what details are needed.

Thanks

-DJ

Comment: Are you reporting a bug? There is a 202 error here https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8770

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the instance is running out of memory. If you are using appstats to profile your calls, try disabling that. Or you can try selecting a larger instance size.